# python requests json argument not converted to URL parameters

Tags: python, django, python-requests

I have a Django backend and can receive and respond to query parameters such when in URL:

```
http://localhost:8000/stac_management/stac/search?bbox=115.378418,5.375398,127.199707,19.352611
```

When using python requests to send a POST, using the params argument also respond well since the query parameters are converted and passed into the url same as above.

```
import requests
import json

#URL='https://api.ops.dev.phl-microsat.upd.edu.ph/stac_management/stac/search'
URL='http://localhost:8000/stac_management/stac/search'
payload = {'bbox': '115.378418,5.375398,127.199707,19.352611'}

response = requests.post(URL, params=payload)
print('url:', response.url)
# url: http://localhost:8000/stac_management/stac/search?bbox=115.378418,5.375398,127.199707,19.352611
```

However, when I use the json argument for request the payload does not convert to query parameters. Thus my backend cannot receive a query parameter.

```
response = requests.post(URL, json=payload)
print('url:', response.url)
# url: http://localhost:8000/stac_management/stac/search
```

I am using a library that will POST to my backend and it is using the json argument for requests. I am having problem receiving the query parameters since what I get is `None`.

I am using Django Viewset and expecting the bbox using:

```
class SearchViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):
    permission_classes = [AllowAny]

    def list(self, request):
        ...
        bbox = request.query_params.get('bbox', None)
```

How can I receive a query parameter when using the json argument from requests into my Django app? Also the fix is should be within my backend since I cannot change the library for using json argument.

Answer (score 0):

Mainly, params is for GET-style URL parameters, data is for POST-style body information. But you can use both at any request.

```
import requests
import json

headers = {'content-type': 'application/json'}
URL='http://localhost:8000/stac_management/stac/search'
payload = {'bbox': '115.378418,5.375398,127.199707,19.352611'}
response = requests.post(URL, data=json.dumps(payload), headers=headers)
```

This should work

Comment: I shouldn't change how I post request since I am using a library that uses json argument. The library has a wrapper that post using a json arg. I am expecting a solution from my Django backend to handle an incoming post with json arg.